# Should I use "ser" or "estar" to translate "The wine cellar should be dark and dry"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, cópulas

The sentence I want to translate is:

> The wine cellar should be dark and dry.

Which of the following would be more appropriate and why?

> La bodega debe **ser** oscura y seca.
>
> La bodega debe **estar** oscura y seca.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it should be the first one, but actually, it could be both depending on the case.

I guess that wine cellars, in general, have to be `dark` and `dry`. So if you are talking about a general case it should be the first one. Let's put it this way:

> All wine cellars should be dark and dry.
>
> Las bodegas deberían ser oscuras y secas.

In the other hand, if this was not the case, and if you were talking about a specific moment for the `wine cellar` (which in this case I do not think it would be often) it should be the seconde one. Let's change the example:

> My house should be clean for this weekend.
>
> Mi casa debería estar limpia para este fin de semana.

This is because you are talking about a specific moment (in time) of the house. It is not how houses are *supposed* to be, it is how they are in a certain period of time. If we change the example a bit again:

> My house has to be bright and white.
>
> Mi casa tiene que ser luminosa y blanca.

It is a state, not a specific moment.

P.S.: Note the gender of the adjectives in the examples, `bodega` is femenine.

***EDIT***

I have to say that, thinking deeply about this, this is what you will find **most** (like 90%) of times (for any example, not just this one). It is true that some people may use the second sentence as a translation for your question. I think that they would mean that `wine cellars` have to be `dark` and `dry` as a moment in time, if you want to have good wine. But as I said, it should be the first one :)

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer. And thanks also for pointing out the mistake in gender which I have now corrected. Just had one question though: Any particular reason to prefer “debería” over “debe” in that example?

Comment: I just answered your other question, which is related to the `debería` and `deber` question. Check it and if you still do not understand, just ask ;)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers point out an ambiguity in your original sentence: *when* should the cellar be dark and dry?

I'd rephrase the original question as

> The wine cellar should *always* be dark and dry.

That translates cleanly to

> La bodega *siempre* debe estar oscura y seca.

and I think it's a sentence you're more likely to actually hear when talking about wine cellars. Otherwise, if the original sentence belongs to a longer paragraph, I'd want to read the context to know how to better translate. Perhaps the text gives a general sense of the time. E.g., in instructions for building or cleaning a wine cellar, the "always" is implied. 
Finally, though it might be fine to say

> La bodega debe ser seca

it's not a sentence that I'd ever write, because "dryness" is not an inherent quality of a cellar, but something that you have to make an effort to obtain.

Answer (score 2):

Think of "ser" as a inherent property of the subject, and "estar" as a temporal property.

So if somebody "is handsome" can be "es guapo" or "está guapo", the first meaning he is a handsome person always and the second one that he looks handsome at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good occasion to use the verb "permanecer". Otherwise, in spanish, "ser" is used as a way to describe the long-run state, while "estar" is used for short-run, varying properties. Similarly we use "estar" when we describe what we now do ("estoy pensando"), while we use "ser" for inherent properties and actions of the subject.