# Meaning of "estar"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, significado

> ¿Estas invitaciones son tuyas?

Here I guess *estas* means "these" and *son* means "are".

In another sentence:

> Mis libros están aquí.

*están* represents "are".

I'm a little bit confused. How can I determine what *estar* means?

Comment: look for accented vowels. Estas - these, estás - (you sing.) are.

Comment: Welcome @yashirq to SE. The verb 'to be' in Spanish is two different verbs 'ser' and 'estar' and I consider them the most difficult verbs to learn. Search in this site for "ser estar" and you will find hundreds of questions. You can start by checking this out http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15646/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-ser-versus-estar

Answer (score 2):

1. *¿**Estas** invitaciones **son** tuyas?*
   Your guess is right: *these* is the plural demonstrative pronoun and *son* is one of the forms of the verb *to be* in Spanish — The other one is *están* (second/third person plural form).
   Don't confuse *estas* and *estás*, the second one is a *to be* form and then the following sentence would be non-sense:

   > <s>*¿Estás vacaciones son tuyas?*</s> But
   >   *¿Estás de vacaciones?* (= Are you on holidays?)
2. *Mis  libros **están** aquí.*
   Words stressed and ending in *n, s* or a *vowel* need the graphic accent. Written like,

   > <s>*Mis libros **estan** aquí*</s>

   makes it readable but incorrectly spelt.
3. *be* forms in Spanish are two: *ser* & *estar*.  Study their conjugations so that you don't get confused with the demonstrative pronoun *este/esta/estos/estas.*
   *está/esté/estás/estés* are conjugated *be* forms for *estar.*

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are using a pronoun, `estas` is the plural of `esta`, which means *these* and *this* each one.

There is also a word you are missing that is `ésta` and `éstas`, which is also *this* and *that*, but when there is no noun. So for example you can say

> Me gustan estas manzanas. *I like these apples*

Which has the noun `manzanas`, *apples*, but you could also say

> Me gustan esas manzanas, pero éstas me gustan más. *I like those apples but I like these more*

The pronunciation for those cases is the same, in the first syllable.

Now, `estar` means always to be (in the first case you had `estas`/`éstas` which is something different).

The conjunction is as follows:

> Estoy (I'm)
>
> Estás (you're)
>
> Está (this is, it is)

and so on.

I believe the use of `estar` is pretty clear as it means *to be*.

Now you also have `son` in your examples, which indeed means *(they) are*, but it's a different verb. In this case is the verb `ser`, which also means *to be*.

Now for your question to how determine if it's about the verb *to be* or the pronoun *these*, among other similar words (`este`, `esté`, etc), the easiest thing is to learn the conjugations of the verb. In most cases you can also determine it from the context. They are never written in the same way, and the pronunciation is also different, so that's what you have to out attention on.